# how to selected checbox in different condition in angular2

Tags: angular

[image]

```
   <tr *ngFor="let item of  _studentList">
    <td  align='center'>{{item.rollno}}</td>
    <td  align='center'>{{item.sname}}</td>      
    <td  align='center'>
        <input type='checkbox' style='height:15px; width:15px;' ng-checked="item.status=='P'" ></td>
```

if student `Present` `checbox` should be `checked` if its `Absent` then it `unchecked` I tried like above but not work

how to do it?

Comment: you can also use this `<input type='checkbox' style='height:15px; width:15px;' checked="{{item.status=='P'}}" >`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ng-checked` is used in angular 1 and not angular 2.
Try

```
  <input type='checkbox' style='height:15px; width:15px;' [checked]="item.status=='P'" >
```